# Gaussian 'around' a given distribution

Tags: python, data, gaussian

I want to find the data points within 0.2 dex of the Main Sequence Relation:
(The main sequence relation is what you can observe in this figure)[image]

Dex is an astronomical jargon which signifies scatter, technically the Gaussian 'around' a distribution. 
I have trouble understanding what the Gaussian 'around' a distribution actually means. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that "around" means that both distributions are added. The usual situation of whatever + Gaussian noise.